# What US State has the most complete rock record?

Tags: time, regional-geology, geologic-layers, age

The title seems self explanatory to me. I thought about it when I was looking at a geologic map of Utah, and it seemed to include an exceptional amount of time. I mean this in the sense that there weren't any enormous gaps in the record. So, is it Utah or a different state?

Comment: what other geological surveys do you compare it to.

Comment: I wasn't comparing it to any survey; I was just looking at a geologic map of Utah and started thinking about it. Should I read the geologic surveys of all states myself?

Comment: to answer your question somebody will have to find the information :) if you do it you might be able to answer your own question and gain some extra reputation.

Comment: There is [this old answer of mine](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/oldest-to-newest-bedrock-in-the-usa-road-trip/12831#12831) which suggests South Dakota, Wisconsin, or Minnesota.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate? It's not my area, but that question appears to be about which areas have different ages of rock, and this one seems to be about which state has the most complete records?